# Как уменьшить нагрузку на процессор используя threading?

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть main файл, и куча вспомогательных модулей, код в которых должен исполнятся  в реальном времени, причем одновременно, удалось реализовать это с помощью потоков `Thread` и циклов `While true` в них, (я новичок, не кидайте камни), но когда число потоков дошло до 6 одновременно выполняющихся, процессор и все его ядра начали долбится в 100%, если у кого есть более производительное решение параллельного выполнения зацикленных модулей, я был бы очень благодарен

Ниже пример main файла с логикой запуска модулей, только тут одновременно запускаются(имитируют запуск), только 2 модуля, а у меня запускаются 6 модулей

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from threading import Thread
import keyboard
import time

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = False
        self.stop = False
        self.exit = False

    def module_one(self):
        while True:
            if self.start == True:
                self.stop = False
                while True:
                    if self.stop == True:
                        self.start = False
                        break
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print('Start module one')
            if self.exit == True:
                break

    def module_two(self):
        while True:
            if self.start == True:
                self.stop = False
                time.sleep(1)
                while True:
                    if self.stop == True:
                        self.start = False
                        time.sleep(1)
                        break
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print('Start module two')
            if self.exit == True:
                break


    def run_programm(self):
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('9'):
                print('Start programm')
                self.start = True
                while True:
                    if keyboard.is_pressed('0'):
                        print('Stop programm')
                        self.stop = True
                        break
            if keyboard.is_pressed('8'):
                self.exit = True
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    object_main = main()

    RUN_CYCLES = Thread(target = object_main.run_programm)
    RUN_CYCLES.start()

    MODULE_ONE_CYCLE = Thread(target = object_main.module_one)
    MODULE_TWO_CYCLE = Thread(target = object_main.module_two)

    MODULE_ONE_CYCLE.start()
    MODULE_TWO_CYCLE.start()

    MODULE_ONE_CYCLE.join()
    MODULE_TWO_CYCLE.join()

    RUN_CYCLES.join()
```

p.s Требуется писать программу на python 2, пишу её на python 2.7

Comment: Ваши потоки никогда не завершат свою работу из-за вечного цикла `while True`. Думаю, начать стоит с переделки их так, чтобы они всё-таки завершали свою работу когда-нибудь

Comment: Не думаю что вечные циклы которые просто напросто проверяют на каждой своей итерации значение переменной, или нажатую клавишу, так сильно грузят систему, вложенные циклы которые выполняют код модулей, конечны, и закончатся в случае нажатии клавиши. До запуска модулей, от нажатой клавиши, загрузка процессора минимальна, дидли дудли начинаются когда пытаюсь циклично выполнять модули в функциях типа `module_one` и `module_two`, предполагаю, что код в этих модулях не должен загружать так сильно систему

Comment: Вложенные циклы действительно конечные, но вот наружние циклы — бесконечные. У них нет никакого break и нет никакого time.sleep — поэтому они будут на 100% грузить систему, безостановочно проверяя истинность значения True и не делая больше ничего.

Comment: Я только что перепроверил на своей машине, до запуска вложенных циклов, загруженность минимальна, это такой себе режим ожидания запуска основной логики программы, я знаю что его лучше переделать, и сделаю это, но это не решит описанной мною выше проблемы

Comment: Исправил пример по вашему совету, на нагрузку не повлияло

Comment: Хоть они и перестали быть вечными, но они по-прежнему будут на 100% грузить систему, проверяя значение `self.exit` миллионы раз в секунду

Comment: Кстати, это также относится и к циклу в run_programm, который миллионы раз в секунду проверяет keyboard.is_pressed — он тоже создаёт 100% нагрузку на систему таким образом. Собственно, если понатыкать хотя бы простейший `time.sleep(0.1)` во все циклы чтобы замедлить их работу — нагрузка пропадает.

Comment: Вы были правы, исправил код как вы указали и все стало гораздо лучше, спасибо!

Comment: Если бы оформили свой ответ я бы мог его отметить как тот, который помог

Comment: Добавляйте time.sleep(0.1) там где циклы не должны отрабатывать миллион раз в секунду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать вместо self.start, self.stop, self.exit, while True и time.sleep, логику основанную на [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event)

`self.start = threading.Event()`

`if self.start.is_set():`

`while not self.stop.is_set():`

`self.start.wait()`

и т.п.